# find the position of character in a substring

Tags: string, swift

How can I find the first position of a character in a substring. Not in the string overall, but the first after a specified character position.

Example:

```
var str = "This is a test string"
//find the position of first "i" after "is"

let position = str.firstPositionOfIAfterPosition(5) // returns 18
```

I know I can find the overall first position with code below. How can I extend this to start looking only after a specified character position?

```
   let position = str.rangeOfString("i").startIndex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "This is a test string"
var targetRange = s.characters.indices
targetRange.startIndex = targetRange.startIndex.advancedBy(6) // skip past
let r = s.rangeOfString("i", options: [], range: targetRange, locale: nil)
// 18..<19
```

Comment: (You can omit the `locale: nil`, that parameter has a default.)

Comment: @MartinR I know, but I wish code completion would show me that. I've filed a bug on this but it keeps coming back to me; Apple seems not to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "This is a test string"


func getIndexAfterString(string: String) -> Int {
    let firstIndex = str.rangeOfString(string)?.startIndex.advancedBy(string.characters.count)
    let i: Int = str.startIndex.distanceTo(firstIndex!)
    let secondIndex = str.substringFromIndex(firstIndex!).rangeOfString("i")?.startIndex
    let j: Int = str.startIndex.distanceTo(secondIndex!)
    return i + j
}

let index: Int = getIndexAfterString(" is ") //18
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to matt's answer, but as `String` extension and with error handling

```
extension String {

  func firstPositionOf(string: String, afterPosition index: Int) -> String.Index?
  {
    if self.isEmpty || self.characters.count - 1 < index { return nil }
    let subRange = Range<String.Index>(self.startIndex.advancedBy(index + 1)..<self.endIndex)
    guard let foundRange = self.rangeOfString(string, options: [], range: subRange) else { return nil }
    return foundRange.startIndex
  }
}

let str = "This is a test string"

let position = str.firstPositionOf("i", afterPosition:5) // -> 18
```